# nodejs desktop-screenshot not working

Tags: node.js, screenshot

```
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');

screenshot("screenshot.png", function(error, complete) {
    if(error)
        console.log("Screenshot failed", error);
    else
        console.log("Screenshot succeeded");
});
```

This code is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/desktop-screenshot and it is not working i.e. throws error "Screenshot failed, no file found", I want to make an app that takes screenshots in nodejs and I found desktop-screenshot useful and short. I changed the path "screenshot.png" to an actual path i.e. "/home/asim/Desktop/myfolder" and that didn't work also, can anybody please tell me how to take screenshots using desktop-screenshot? Thank you.

Comment: You may need to install scrot for Linux platforms as in https://github.com/johnvmt/node-desktop-screenshot/issues/6

Comment: That solved the issue :) Thanks